# Xcode Source Control Options Still Gray after Checking Out

Tags: xcode, git, cocos2d-x

I created a project in Cocos2d-x, and I set up a repository on BitBucket. Then I clicked "Check Out", and selected the repository that I set up, and set up a local folder on my computer. All is fine. But the "Commit", "Push", "Pull", and other options are still gray. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode version control has always left a bit to be desired. Here is someone that has it working: https://www.davidlaristudios.com/2013/11/adding-a-bitbucket-remote-repository-to-xcode-5/